# I'm making a discord bot, and I want it to send a question in a channel referenced in the command. How do I do this?

Tags: python, discord, bots

For example, if I type bot.send #general, the bot will send a predetermined message in the #general channel. How would I make this command? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel, *, message):
    await channel.send(message)
```

for this example im gonna assume the prefix is `.`
Now u can do: `.send #general Hi`